MCP3461 ADC datasheet question
I'm designing a board to read some analog sensor signals. I decided to use the MCP3461 ADC and an STM32F042 to read the ADC through SPI. This ADC includes an IRQ signal that releases interrupts in certain events, such as when the data is ready to read. However, I've run out of pins of the STM32, and I want to know if this IRQ signal is needed to correctly read the ADC. If not, how would I know when to read the ADC?

Refer to section 6.2.6 DEVICE ADDRESS AND STATUS BYTE DURING CONTROL BYTE:

for applications that do not connect the existing IRQ pin, the polling
of the IRQ status can still be done by reading the IRQ register
continuously.

You need to determine if your application can handle the extra latency involved with serially polling the regitser instead of reacting to the dedicated interrupt pin.
